# How do I use sudo with alias in zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Say I have these two in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'
alias boot27='grub-reboot 4 && reboot'
```

`boot27` gives `boot27: command not found`.
    If I change the alias to `'nocorrect sudo '` or just `'sudo '`, it works, but then other things like `mkdir` give `nocorrect: command not found`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to clarify, you run `sudo boot27` and get `boot27: command not found` because since `sudo` is an alias, bash stops scanning for aliases and does not recognize `boot27` as one. As discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22043/85695), one way of dealing with this is adding a space at the end of the alias definition.

Adding the space allows bash to recognize `boot27` but the problem now is that your root account is not set to use zsh so `sudo` starts a bash shell instead. `nocorrect` is a `zsh` thing, `bash` has no idea what it is so it complains.

The simplest way to fix this would be to  set root's shell to `/bin/zsh`:

```
sudo chsh
```

Then set your alias with the space:

```
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '
```

---

Your `boot27` alias has another problem though. I assume you run it as `sudo boot27`, the shell will read the alias and expand that to:

```
sudo grub-reboot 4 && reboot
```

So, it will run `grub-reboot` as root but it will run `reboot` as a normal user. What you want is either to change your alias to

```
alias boot27='grub-reboot 4 && sudo reboot'
```

and run it as `sudo boot27`, or to change your alias to

```
alias boot27='sudo grub-reboot 4 && sudo reboot'
```

and run it without `sudo`, just `boot27`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I have privileges to reboot as normal user, so I think I'll just leave it as is.

Comment: @terdon I've got a problem with this approach. I've detailed it in a question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/749314/how-do-you-set-alias-sudo-nocorrect-sudo-correctly), but basically this approach doesn't seem to work for me (while `alias sudo='sudo '` works, as does `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'`). Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: @MikeH-R I posted an answer to your question. The issue is already addressed in my answer here, you need to change the `sudo` shell to `zsh`.

Comment: Is there any reason for concern about aliasing non-sudo commands to sudo-prefixed ones? There is `sudo -k` (alone to invalidate cached credentials, or prefixing a command prompt for credentials on each invocation). I have `update` aliased to `sudo apt-get update`, etc. On an unrelated note, I also have 'f***ing' aliased to sudo.