# How do you set alias sudo='nocorrect sudo ' correctly?

Tags: linux, zsh, sudo

Until Recently I had `alias sudo='sudo '` in my `.zshrc` file. Today I ran into this error on trying to do `sudo mv`:

```
➜  ~  sudo mv nginx.conf.orig nginx.conf.orig2
sudo: nocorrect: command not found
```

Now googling around I found out that this seemed to be to do with some commands that are prefixed with `nocorrect` and that I could fix this with `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'`.

However the problem comes when I try to set my alias to `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '` to allow myself to use additional aliases. I also ensured that my su was using zsh as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/605417/how-do-i-use-sudo-with-alias-in-zsh).

```
➜  ~  alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '            
➜  ~  sudo mv nginx.conf.orig nginx.conf.orig2
sudo: nocorrect: command not found
➜  ~  alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'                           
➜  ~  sudo mv nginx.conf.orig nginx.conf.orig2
➜  ~  su
Password: 
michaelarch# ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
25831 pts/1    00:00:00 zsh
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

EDIT: `alias sudo='sudo '` allows you to use aliases with your sudo commands, for an example see below.

```
➜  ~  alias cat='echo hello'     
➜  ~  echo goodbye > example.txt
➜  ~  cat example.txt           
hello example.txt
➜  ~  sudo cat example.txt 
goodbye
➜  ~  alias sudo='sudo '
➜  ~  sudo cat example.txt
hello example.txt
```

For some more info on my shell:

```
➜  ~  sudo chsh                               
Changing shell for root.
New shell [/usr/bin/zsh]:    
➜  ~  unalias sudo; alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '
➜  ~  echo $SHELL; which sudo                   
/usr/bin/zsh
sudo: aliased to nocorrect sudo 
➜  ~  sudo mv nginx.conf.orig2 nginx.conf.orig  
sudo: nocorrect: command not found
➜  ~  which mv
mv: aliased to nocorrect mv
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `alias sudo='sudo '`?

Comment: @mpy it allows you to use other aliased commands with sudo which you can't otherwise do, I'll put an example up.

Comment: I see... I suspect that this is the problem: You define a `sudo` alias, then a `nocorrect sudo` alias _on top_. So finally `sudo nocorrect sudo ...` will be executed and throws you `sudo: nocorrect: command not found` as `nocorrect` is a shell builtin. Try `unalias sudo; alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '`.

Comment: @mpy good idea. when I read that I thought you were right but trying it unfortunately it didn't work: `unalias sudo; alias sudo='nocorrect sudo ';` `➜  ~  sudo mv nginx.conf.orig2 nginx.conf.orig  
sudo: nocorrect: command not found`

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL; which sudo` say?

Comment: `echo $SHELL; which sudo;
/usr/bin/zsh;
sudo: aliased to nocorrect sudo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior is reproducible with:

```
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '
alias mv='nocorrect mv '
```

So, when executing `sudo mv foo bar` this gets expanded to

```
nocorrect sudo nocorrect mv foo bar
```

and throws an error as *nocorrect* is a shell reserved word and cannot be handled by sudo.

The reason that the mv alias gets expanded is that you define `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '` with a trailing blank, which enables alias expansion afterwards. Without that trailing blank this example works, but you loose the capability to use aliases after sudo completely.

A workaround to have alias expansion generally after sudo, but to prevent the error with `sudo mv` escape the `mv` command when using it with sudo:

```
sudo \mv foo bar
```

This prevents the alias expansion of mv.

Comment: @Mike H-R I'm pretty sure you can solve your issue more elegant, perhaps by defining a zstyle for mv that the _correct completer isn't used and you don't need the mv alias. That's only an idea, and I'm no pro at that, so thats why I included no code for that approach. Btw. to just make sure: You need the CORRECT_ALL option to correct all commands _and_ arguments -- CORRECT for correction of commands _only_ it's sufficient?

Comment: hahaha, I just wrote a giant in depth answer but I like yours better. have a `+1` and an accept.

Comment: +1 but a minor quibble: `nocorrect` is not a builtin it is a "reserved word" whatever that means (you can check with `type nocorrect`).

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, corrected the terminology.

Comment: @terdon: Btw, IMHO you can overload a shell builtin with a function, but not a reserved word.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've been digging into this for a while and have found some stuff on the zsh mailing list. There doesn't seem to be one "silver bullet" solution but a bunch of different solutions which do different things. I'm going to post what I've done (which is a bit of a cop out) but also explore the other approaches and their problems. I'm personally going to go with:

```
➜  ~  alias sudo='sudo '
➜  ~  alias nsudo='nocorrect sudo'
```

EDIT:

I am now going to go with

```
sudo \mv foo bar
```

for the cases where I need this as descibed by @mpy in the alternate answer.

/EDIT

because it will allow me to use aliases most of the time and when they complain because they're aliased to nocorrect I can use `nsudo` so that I don't accidentally clobber my files.

Better approaches are from the zsh mailing lists. There appears to be two threads that I've found on this. One from 1999 [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1999/msg00150.html) (that's the question, see the follow ups, especially [this one](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1999/msg00152.html) which solves the `noglob` problem. I am unsure if it solves nocorrect as well (does noglob imply nocorrect? otherwise I don't think it does, please comment)

```
alias sudo='my_sudo '

function my_sudo {
    while [[ $# > 0 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
        command) shift ; break ;;
        nocorrect|noglob) shift ;;
        *) break ;;
        esac
    done
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]; then
        command sudo zsh
    else
        noglob command sudo $@
    fi
}
```

Which satisfies both of my requirements from my question:

```
➜  ~  alias cat='echo hello'     
➜  ~  echo goodbye > example.txt
➜  ~  sudo cat
hello
➜  ~  sudo mv example.txt2 example.txt
```

It also seems that this came up again [in 2008](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg01229.html) on the mailing list with a solution like so:

```
alias sudo='noglob do_sudo '
function do_sudo
{
    integer glob=1
    local -a run
    run=( command sudo )
    if [[ $# -gt 1 && $1 = -u ]]; then
        run+=($1 $2)
        shift ; shift
    fi
    (($# == 0)) && 1=/bin/zsh
    while (($#)); do
        case "$1" in
        command|exec|-) shift; break ;;
        nocorrect) shift ;;
        noglob) glob=0; shift ;;
        *) break ;;
        esac
    done
    if ((glob)); then
        PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" $run $~==*
    else
        PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" $run $==*
    fi
}
```

Which seems to be doing a lot that I admittedly don't fully understand. This seems to ignore autocorrect (as stated by the author).

Comment: Yes, the zsh mailing list is a huge source for high-quality solutions -- and I appreciate your efforts to write such an elaborate answer. +1 :)